# Supperposed plot of a statistic and weight using ggplo2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I want to create a plot showing a particular statistic and the weight associated with each bin of my graphic. Since it is not recommended in `ggplot2` to create a double-y-axis plot, I followed the advice and stack two plots one over the other. Below is a minimum reproducible example of what I did :

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1L)
data <- data.table(x=1:10, y=10000+1000*runif(10), weight=runif(10))

plot_stat <- ggplot(data) +
  geom_line(aes(x, y), stat="identity") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), 
axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.line.x=element_blank())

plot_weight <- ggplot(data) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_bar(aes(x, weight), stat="identity")

grid.arrange(plot_stat, plot_weight, nrow = 2, heights = c(0.7, 0.3))
```

The output of this is the following :

[image]

My problem is that the reserved space for axis labelling is not the same for both of the graphs. I would like the axis line to be perfectly aligned no matter what the axis labels are.

This is the result (manually edited) I want :

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the library `cowplot` . . .

```
library(cowplot)

plot_grid(plot_stat, plot_weight, ncol = 1, align = "v")
```

One thing to be aware of is that `cowplot` will change your default ggplot theme, so to change it back do the following: `theme_set(theme_gray())`.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I'll give it a try and mark your answer as accepted if it does what I want! :)